# To Do List Example

Tags: android

I am new to Android App Development and have a small problem.

I have tried to follow an example to create a to do list app. However it doesn't work even though I have copied it exactly.

It shows no errors when I run it however, a blank screen appears and after a few seconds it closes and says "Unfortunately, ToDoList has stopped."

Does anyone know what this problem might be?

**Code**

```
 package com.paad.todolist;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);
            final EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText);

            final ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
            final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;

            aa = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,todoItems);

            myListView.setAdapter(aa);


        myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()   {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)   {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)    ||
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))   {
                        todoItems.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());
                        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        myEditText.setText("");
                        return true;
                    }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

**Layout XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/EditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/addItemHint"
        android:contentDescription="@string/addItemContentDescription"
    />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />        

</LinearLayout>
```

Log:

```
02-10 20:03:53.850: D/AndroidRuntime(24220): Shutting down VM
02-10 20:03:53.850: W/dalvikvm(24220): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f0a2a0)
02-10 20:03:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(24220): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 20:03:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(24220): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.paad.todolist/com.paad.todolist.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-10 20:03:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(24220):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
02-10 20:03:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(24220):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
02-10 20:03:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(24220):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-10 20:03:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(24220):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
02-10 20:03:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(24220):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-10 20:03:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(24220):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-10 20:03:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(24220):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-10 20:03:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(24220):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 20:03:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(24220):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-10 20:03:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(24220):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
02-10 20:03:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(24220):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
02-10 20:03:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(24220):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-10 20:03:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(24220): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-10 20:03:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(24220):    at com.paad.todolist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
02-10 20:03:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(24220):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
02-10 20:03:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(24220):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
02-10 20:03:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(24220):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
02-10 20:03:53.850: E/AndroidRuntime(24220):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please paste LogCat output also...without that cant help.

Comment: Your Code is working fine and also i have tested it just now. SO pls post your logcat output so i can help you further.

Comment: Hi, What is the logcat output?

Comment: Oh my god... you dont know what is logcat output..

See my below images

Comment: What is line 30 of `MainActivity`? Also, try cleaning your project.

Comment: Line 30 is  `myListView.setAdapter(aa);`

Comment: if you are using only list in your activity then extend your class to `listActivity` instead its a good practice...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you properly didn't define your activities in the android manifest XML.

Comment: Can you be more specific? This isn't an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. You might not have defined your activity in manifest as pointed out earlier. For this do the following in your manifest file which is in the root of your project.

```
<activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Activityname" >
</activity>
```